# Using sort to get max and min values from a interval of a slice

Tags: go

i have this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/U9DOVKBBmRH) in playground. I was using a sort to get max and min value from a slice/array. The problem started when I needed to get the values in a interval of x periods.
If you run the code you will in the lasts print there is a value of 1.0407, but the x periods before there isn't this value anymore, this value is way far from the period of x.
So my question is, why did he peeked this value? While min didn't.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    var x = []float64{1.0073, 1.0129, 1.014, 1.017, 1.0173, 1.0171, 1.0171, 1.0174, 1.0154, 1.0142, 1.0116, 1.0116, 1.0118, 1.0084, 1.0087, 1.0086, 1.0077, 1.0154, 1.0155, 1.0207, 1.0218, 1.0273, 1.0257, 1.0244, 1.0243, 1.0237, 1.026, 1.0251, 1.0239, 1.025, 1.0246, 1.0245, 1.0234, 1.024, 1.0247, 1.0229, 1.0274, 1.0326, 1.0319, 1.0314, 1.0331, 1.0301, 1.0311, 1.0307, 1.028, 1.0298, 1.0305, 1.0296, 1.0293, 1.0296, 1.0291, 1.0288, 1.029, 1.029, 1.0313, 1.0315, 1.0318, 1.0366, 1.0387, 1.0363, 1.0366, 1.0353, 1.036, 1.0364, 1.0369, 1.0341, 1.0326, 1.0345, 1.033, 1.0316, 1.0324, 1.032, 1.0325, 1.032, 1.0325, 1.0317, 1.0317, 1.0324, 1.0335, 1.036, 1.0368, 1.034, 1.0347, 1.035, 1.0354, 1.039, 1.0407, 1.0374, 1.0362, 1.0349, 1.0326, 1.0285, 1.0298, 1.0301, 1.0318, 1.0326, 1.0329, 1.032, 1.0303, 1.0305, 1.0305, 1.0311, 1.0303, 1.0303, 1.0295, 1.0304, 1.031, 1.0305, 1.0305, 1.0288, 1.0287, 1.029, 1.0289, 1.0293, 1.0299, 1.0297, 1.0286, 1.028, 1.0292, 1.0292, 1.0286, 1.0295, 1.0282, 1.0291, 1.029, 1.0292, 1.0287, 1.0294, 1.0274, 1.0267, 1.0266, 1.0249, 1.0245, 1.0226, 1.0221, 1.0237, 1.0243, 1.0264, 1.025, 1.0263, 1.0268, 1.0256, 1.0263, 1.0257, 1.0253, 1.0246, 1.0257, 1.0263, 1.0258, 1.026, 1.0264, 1.0266, 1.0295, 1.0283, 1.0309, 1.0296, 1.0299, 1.0294, 1.0287, 1.0277, 1.0285, 1.03, 1.0323, 1.032, 1.0315, 1.0325, 1.0336, 1.0336, 1.0337, 1.0337, 1.0326, 1.0328, 1.0329, 1.0335, 1.0327, 1.0347, 1.0331, 1.0359, 1.0357, 1.0332, 1.0328, 1.0308, 1.0307, 1.0304, 1.0303, 1.0271, 1.0284, 1.0293, 1.0308, 1.0312, 1.0309, 1.0311, 1.0309, 1.0305, 1.0314, 1.0306, 1.0302, 1.0299, 1.0294, 1.0286, 1.0292, 1.0288, 1.0295, 1.0301, 1.0304, 1.0286, 1.0275, 1.0265, 1.0262, 1.0271, 1.027, 1.0263, 1.026, 1.0258, 1.0257, 1.0257, 1.0261, 1.0264, 1.0242, 1.0256, 1.0265, 1.0263, 1.0258, 1.0264, 1.0253, 1.0243, 1.0239, 1.0243, 1.0258, 1.0234, 1.0227, 1.0181, 1.0189, 1.0117, 1.0128, 1.0143, 1.0154, 1.0154, 1.0144, 1.0122, 1.0129, 1.0123, 1.0128, 1.0133, 1.0136, 1.0134, 1.0134, 1.0142, 1.0132, 1.0127, 1.0113, 1.0122, 1.0119, 1.0105, 1.0108, 1.0079, 1.0082, 1.0082, 1.0091, 1.0105, 1.0121, 1.0122, 1.0115, 1.0123, 1.0118, 1.0123, 1.0111, 1.0106, 1.0099, 1.01, 1.0107, 1.0111, 1.0103, 1.0128, 1.0115, 1.0109, 1.0081, 1.0083, 1.0096, 1.0089, 1.0097, 1.0106, 1.0121, 1.0124, 1.0136, 1.0118, 1.0134, 1.0137, 1.0152, 1.0147, 1.0141, 1.0144, 1.0139, 1.0145, 1.0146, 1.0156, 1.0145, 1.014, 1.014, 1.0124}
    var period = 5
    var highest float64
    var lowest float64
    for i, v := range x {
        if i < period {
            continue
        }
        var correctHighest, correctLowest = MaxMin(x[i-period : i])
        fmt.Println("Correct -", "Price:", v, "Highest:", correctHighest, "Lowest:", correctLowest)
    }
    for i, v := range x {
        if i < period {
            continue
        }
        var correctHighest, correctLowest = MaxMin(x[i-period : i])
        fmt.Println("Correct -", "Highest:", correctHighest, "Lowest:", correctLowest)
        highest = Max(x[i-period : i]...)
        lowest = Min(x[i-period : i]...)
        fmt.Println("Price:", v, "Highest:", highest, "Lowest:", lowest)
    }
}

// Both does not work
func Max(n ...float64) float64 {
    sort.Float64s(n)
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return 0.
    }
    return n[len(n)-1]
}
func Min(n ...float64) float64 {
    sort.Float64s(n)
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return 0.
    }
    return n[0]
}

// New code that works
func MaxMin(n []float64) (float64, float64) {
    if len(n) == 0 {
        return 0., 0.
    }
    var max float64
    var min = math.MaxFloat64
    for _, value := range n {
        if value > max {
            max = value
        }
        if value < min {
            min = value
        }
    }
    return max, min
}
```

Comment: `Min()` in the edge case of `len==0` should probably return `math.MaxFloat64` not `0`.

Comment: A small note: if the slice is not sorted already then sorting it just to find the min/max is going to be slower than a simple loop that scans for the min/max element.

Comment: Other small note: the MaxMin function is not really correct. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that slices are references to a backing array and sort sorts the slice in place. What this means is that the calls to sort.Float64s are actually modifying (sorting) the contents of the x slice (more precisely, of subslices of x, but the backing array is the same).

As I mentioned in my comment above, using sort just for finding the min/max is not a good idea, as it's going to be slower than a simple loop that scans for min/max. But if you really want to use it, you need to make deep copies of those slices before passing them to sort.Float64s.

---

Also small note about the code above: your MaxMin function is not really correct in case all elements are negative, or in case they are all NaN. You may want to do something like this instead: https://godbolt.org/z/E5e5q7ePa (not tested).

```golang
func MinMax(n []float64) (min float64, max float64) {
    min, max = math.NaN(), math.NaN()
    for _, e := range n {
        if e < min || (math.IsNaN(min) && !math.IsNaN(e)) {
            min = e
        }
        if e > max || (math.IsNaN(max) && !math.IsNaN(e)) {
            max = e
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: right! my mistake in previous comment. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters `If the final argument is assignable to a slice type []T, it is passed unchanged as the value for a ...T parameter if the argument is followed by .... In this case no new slice is created.`